# How to randomly generate a fixed number of points for different space dimension in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I want to create an n-dimensional array with the constant number of random points and find the closest one to the origin in python.

To be exact I want to create uniformly distributed 100 random points in an n-dimensional array, dimensions range 1 to 10, then find the one which has the smallest distance to the origin. I will repeat this process 50 times at each dimension and get the average value of the smallest distance to avoid wrong values caused by randomness. Obviously, as the dimensions get higher this smallest distance to te origin will grow and I will plot this grow.

So, I tried to use [numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) but I don't know how to set size of this array. Should it include a tuple with 10 elements inside to create a 10-dim array? If yes, how can I set this tuple? For example a tuple (1,2,3...,10) is a good choice? I've lost in this point. Or size=(10,10) creates 10-dim array?

Another option I've found is [numpy.random.uniform()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) which also includes size option. I've the same problem here, how to set size?

I couldn't properly understand how n-dimensional array is used. Could you share your intuition to help me understand how to create an n-dimensional array?

Comment: Are you trying to (random) sample N points from a n-dimensional space?  The preceding feat can be accomplished like this `arr = np.random.xx((N, n))` where the argument to the function is the tuple `(N, n)` where `N` dictates the number of rows and `n` the number of columns.  You use it like this `for point in arr: dist=point@point` or whatever you need to do.  Re the downvotes and the closing votes, the question is poorly written, and this is why I posted a comment: I can not clearly understand what you're asking.  If you like more help, please try to [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape parameter will determine how each dimension will look. You likely want an array where each dimension is the same: 10x10 is a square with 100 values (10 rows, 10 columns); 10x10x10 is a cube with 1000 values (10 layers with 10 rows and 10 columns) etc. Numpy represents a n-dimensional shape using a n-valued tuple: the shape of `(100, 100, 100)` represents a 3-dimensional array with 100 layers, 100 rows and 100 columns.

If you make different axes unequal, you will get a misshapen space (5x10x10 would be like a cube that got sawed in half), and you probably don't want the effect of that shortened dimension on your data.

*However* - you don't actually need an `ndarray` for what you need, just a bit of maths. Because you just need to pick some points in n-dimensional space - there's nothing to store there. A random point on a square with coordinates from 0 to 1 might be at `(0.17263, 0.89837)`, for example. A random point in 3D space: `(0.2, 0.8, 0.413)`, why not. So all you need is actually a point, which is a n-valued tuple (or a n-valued vector, which is a 1-dimensional `ndarray` with n values!). You can calculate the distance of the point from origin by a simple math formula.

If you represent one point using a 1-dimensional vector with n values, you can also represent 100 points as a 2-dimensional array of `100 x n`. And `numpy` lets you find out the distance to the origin very easily using `linalg.norm`.

Even better - you can repeat it 50 times if you just layer this data in the third dimension 50 times!

All together now:

```
[np.mean(
    np.min(
        np.linalg.norm(
            np.random.uniform(size=(50, 100, n)),
            axis=2),
        axis=1)
    )
    for n in range(1, 10)
]
# => [0.009492603803501707, 0.09181966148462747, 0.24366046555716356, 
#     0.4013816188406919, 0.530519283865695, 0.6486607488450368, 
#     0.7944752716376989, 0.892977161731248, 0.9967767337128051]
```

So for each dimension `n` from 1 to 10, we make a bunch of random numbers (from 0 to 1 by default, you can change it by another argument to `uniform`): `50 x 100 x n`. 50 layers for 50 different experiments; 100 for 100 points in each experiment; n for n dimensions per point. Then we find the distance to origin using `linalg.norm`: `axis=2` is telling us that it is the third (third = #2!) dimension of this array that we'll be squaring and summing and rooting, the one with `n` values. We end up with 50x100 array of distances. Then we find the minimum along the second axis, the one with 100 distances now, resulting in a vector with 50 minimums. Finally, the average is calculated. The average for each dimension is collected by list comprehension into an array with 10 values, one average for each number of dimensions from 1 to 10.